# Passing string from .NET to native (64-bit)

Tags: c#, c++, 64-bit, pinvoke

I am having an issue passing a simple string from my .NET app, compiled as 64-bit, to my native DLL, also compiled as 64-bit.

C++ signature:

```
DllExport void SetFoo(LPWSTR foo);
```

C# signature:

```
[DllImport(Library, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern void SetFoo(
     [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string foo);
```

Then I run the following code in C#:

```
X.SetFoo("some string");
```

When it reaches the debugger in the DLL, the value is swearing at me in Chinese: `Ⴐ虘翺`

When I change both the .NET and native code to 32-bit, the value I get in the debugger is the correct string. Where am I being stupid?

Minimal reproduction as a Visual Studio 2015 Solution: [download here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12591686/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip)

To reproduce:

- Create a new Visual Studio solution with a WinForms project.
- Add a Win32 Project, of type DLL to the solution
- Add the following files:

Foo.h:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec( dllexport ) void SetFoo(LPWSTR);
}
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Foo.h"

DllExport void SetFoo(LPWSTR foo) 
{

}
```

- Set a breakpoint on the opening brace in `SetFoo`
- Add a button to the winforms form
- Double click it, and call `SetFoo("abc123")`.
- Implement `SetFoo`:

Form1.cs:

```
[DllImport("Win32Project1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,  CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void SetFoo(string text);
```

- Change the apps to build in 64-bit mode by opening Configuration Manager.
- Set Win32Project1 to build as x64
- Set WindowsFormApplication1 to build as x64, by picking platform new, pick x64, OK.
- Change the output directory of WindowsFormsApplication1 to match the output directory of the other app.
- Start without debugging.
- Attach debugger (Ctrl+Alt+P) by setting `Attach to` to `Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code, Native code` and finding the process.
- Observe value at breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you interpret ANSI encoded latin text as UTF-16 you see Chinese characters. That's clearly what is happening. So your C# code is sending ANSI encoded text somehow.

The p/invoke would be better written like this:

```
[DllImport(Library, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern void SetFoo(string foo);
```

The `[in]` is not needed, it is the default. And the `MarshalAs` is pointless since you specified `CharSet.Unicode`. However, neither change affects the semantics.

The only sound explanations for what you describe in the question are:

- The actual code is not as you have described it, or
- There is a defect in the debugger.

I suggest that you change the unmanaged function to

```
DllExport void SetFoo(LPWSTR foo) 
{
    MessageBoxW(0, L"", foo, MB_OK);
}
```

If the message box displays the correct text then the conclusion would appear to be that the debugger is defective.

Comment: David, thanks for your comment, but this is the case. I have reproduced a minimal solution and [put it in my Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12591686/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip). Run it without debugging, and then attach the debugger (with native support) after it has started, but before you press the button.

Comment: Please include your minimal repro in the question. Off site links are no good. When I use the code in my answer, it works correctly.

Comment: I've added a link to the solution in the question. There are quite a few steps to set it up to fail, so I suggest looking at the solution and seeing it fail.

Comment: Off site links are not very useful. I don't know why you won't make an MCVE here.

Comment: I've done it now. It took 10 minutes just to write it up. The solution is a lot easier for everyone to use.

Comment: What happens when you do `MessageBoxW(0, L"", foo, MB_OK)` in the unmanaged code?

Comment: That works. It outputs a message box with caption "abc123". Is this just a debugger bug?

Comment: This would appear to be a debugger defect.